# How can I change the ActionLink behavior?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

Been new to MVC 2, how can we get a link as:

```
http://localhost:13269/Terms
```

instead

```
http://localhost:13269/Frontend/Terms
```

as this is the result of:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Terms & Conditions", "Terms", "Frontpage")%>
```

even if I don't specify the `Controller` like `<%: Html.ActionLink("Terms & Conditions", "Terms")%>`

as I changed the route to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Frontend", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a new route definition (declare this before the default route)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultFontEnd", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Frontend", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```